# Explicit solution to the advection-reaction equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, linear-pde

Consider the advection-equation equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t) + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,t) + u(x,t) = 0, \quad (x,t) \in (0,2\pi)\times (0,T),$$
with boundary conditions $u(x,0) = \sin(x)$, $u(0,t) = u(2\pi,t) = -\sin(t)$.

I'm trying to get wolfram alpha to give me a solution but i can't, how can I know if there is in fact a solution given those boundary conditions or not?

More precisely, I'm trying to find an explicit solution, but don't know how to proceed. I already found a numerical solution, so ideally I should be able to compute its accuracy.

Thank you.

Comment: The boundary conditions, $u$ at $x=0,2\pi$, are incompatible with the initial condition, $u$ for $t=0$. Can you give us some broader context, e.g. what's the problem origin...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting $u(x,t)=v(t-x,t+x)$ transforms the equation to
$$
2\partial_2v+v=0
$$
so that 
$$
u(x,t)=e^{-(t+x)/2}w(t-x)
$$
This implies that
$$
e^{t/2+s}u(s, t+s)=w(t)=e^{t/2}u(0,t)=e^{t/2+2\pi}u(2\pi,t+2\pi)
$$
which is not compatible with the boundary conditions, as they would require $1=e^{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it turns out there is a solution:

$$u(x,t) = \begin{cases} e^{-x}\sin(x-t), &x<t\\ e^{-t}\sin(x-t), &x \geq t \end{cases}.$$

This is in fact a $C^1$ function, which solves the original PDE, and satisfies all the boundary conditions.

Comment: Well, except the $u(2\pi,t)=sin(-t)$ is not satisfied... Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

The advection-reaction equation needs only one boundary condition, because the highest $x$ derivative has order of 1. Based on the velocity, which is the coefficient of the $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ term which is equal to 1, the direction of advection is from left to right. As a result, you will need a boundary condition on the left side at $x=0$ and the boundary condition at the right side $x=2\pi$ is superfluous.